# Test for equivalence of algebraic expressions

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, numerical-methods, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

We are looking for the most efficient (most recent, or best) techniques to check if two algebraic expressions (elementary, Calculus-type functions) are equivalent (or if an expression is equivalent to zero, which is the so-called "zero-equivalence" problem). 
So far we came across two papers that seem to be relatively easy to implement:

*"Determining the equivalence of algebraic expressions by hash coding" by William Martin, 1971*

and

*"Determining equivalence of expressions in random polynomial time" by Gaston Gonnet, 1984*

but both are not easy to read and it seems like there are many details missing.

Here is the question: is there any more recent research in this direction? Maybe, a book or a paper which is more accessible?

Best,
Denis

Comment: Could you be more precise about what kind of function you would like to test? When you say algebraic expression, do you mean a polynomial? In this case, you might be interested in the [Schwarz-Zippel-Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz–Zippel_lemma) which yields a very easy randomized algorithm: Simply evaluate your polynomials at sufficiently many random points.

Comment: Jesko, we're interested in checking identities of the type ln(e^{x^2-1}) - (x-1)(x+1) = 0, or sin(2x^4) - 2sin(x^4)cos(x^4) = 0, that is, identities one would encounter in Calculus. Checking at random points is an option but it has its disadvantages such as overflow and rounding errors. So, the first direction we're taking at the moment is reduction to finite fields. Schwarz-Zippel Lemma is great but it's not enough in our case.

Comment: To be honest, that sounds very difficult to me. However, computer algebra systems can do this to a certain degree. I am reasonably sure I would suggest Buchberger's book on computer algebra, had I read it. Seriously, I do not know how this is done at all, but I am quite sure that existing computer algebra systems implement algorithms that are well-known and covered in graduate textbooks. Unless someone more knowledgeable posts here, I suggest you dig through some of them.

Comment: This question also has been reposted at http://mathoverflow.net/q/142082/

Comment: Have you tried using some computer algebra system to check for something like `simplify(expression1-expression2) = 0` ?

Comment: @DenisSerbin: How do you define $\sin$ and $\ln$ over finite fields? -- You can also use Taylor arithmetic with truncation at very high degrees and evaluation of the Taylor polynomials at several random points. If all coefficients of the result are numerically zero, this would also strongly hint at equivalent expressions.